# OpenProcess handle invalid for ReadProcessMemory

Tags: c++, winapi, error-handling

I've made this simple class to open a process and read memory from it:
The problem is when I call `ReadDWORD` with any memory address `ReadProcessMemory` fails with error code 6: `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE, The handle is invalid`. And I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

If I put the `OpenProcess` part in the `ReadDWORD` function it works fine. Is there something wrong with how I store the handle? Why does it become invalid before I use it?

**Memory.h**

```
#ifndef MEMORY_H
#define MEMORY_H

#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "psapi.lib")
#include <iostream>

class Memory
{
public:
    Memory();
    Memory(DWORD offset);
    ~Memory();

    DWORD ReadDWORD(DWORD addr);
private:
    HANDLE m_hProc;
    DWORD m_Offset;

};

#endif
```

**Memory.cpp**

```
#include "Memory.h"

Memory::Memory()
{
    Memory(0);
}

Memory::Memory(DWORD offset)
{
    m_hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, 5444); // 5444 is the PID of a process I'm testing this with
    m_Offset = offset;
}

Memory::~Memory()
{
    CloseHandle(m_hProc);
}

DWORD Memory::ReadDWORD(DWORD addr)
{
    // Optional memory offset
    addr += m_Offset;

    DWORD value = -1;
    int result = ReadProcessMemory(m_hProc, (LPVOID)addr, &value, sizeof(DWORD), NULL);
    if (result == 0)
        std::cout << "ReadProcessMemory error: " << GetLastError() << std::endl;

    return value;
}
```

Comment: what is the `m_hProc` value? there is a chance that OpenProcess fails in `Memory::Memory` ctor. Also note that you can't just read random addresses of remote processes, typically correct virtual addresses are passed somehow. e.g. via IPC. Finally, hardcoding PID is not a good idea, you'll have to change it everytime you restard you testing app.

Comment: I've checked m_hProc in Memory::Memory and it doesn't fail. In ReadDWORD m_hProc is different to what it is in Memory::Memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Memory::Memory()
{
    Memory(0);
}
```

This isn't doing what you think its doing: it's not actually calling the other constructor, instead it's creating a temporary that gets discarded. So you are opening the process, but in a separate temporary object, while this object remains uninitialized.

Safer approach is to have a separate Initialize(offset) method that you call from both ctors.

(The advice in the other answers is also good; check your return values, and where you get a E_INVALID_HANDLE, check that the handle is something that looks like a handle. Or set a breakpoint at the OpenHandle and ReadProcessMemory and check that the same value is being used in both places. C++ is often full of surprises, and there's often no substitute for just stepping through the code to make sure it's doing what you think it's doing.)

Answer (score 0):

To access other processes, you *often* need to enable certain privileges. `SeDebugPrivilege` comes to mind. See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185215). Otherwise see the suggestion from Hans Passant (i.e. `GetLastError`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use RtlAdjustPrivilege function to get SeDebugPrivilege.

```
NTSTATUS NTAPI RtlAdjustPrivilege(ULONG,BOOLEAN,BOOLEAN,PBOOLEAN); /*This is the
protoype of RtlAdjustPrivilege function.*/
```